# Objective c zooming and relative positioning : Math

Tags: objective-c, math, zooming

I've a UIScroll view which has a UIImageView.
I have written the code for zooming.

Now lets say I've the labels at
0,10
10,10

for the image at initial size.
But when the image zooms, these labels still remain at the same spot. I want the labels to move to the correct position when zoomed in and out.

How can this be accomplished.
lets say there is a square of 10x10 at the origin 0,0
I've a label at 0,10 and 10,10

Now when we zoom to 2x  the size of square is 20x20
so I want the label at 0,20 and 20,20.

I hope my doubt is now clear.

Comment: What you mean by `code for zooming`? To which view you added your labels?

Comment: Ive added the Labels to the scrollView. And by code for zooming, I mean, I can TapToZoom and Pinch to Zoom on the scroll view.

Comment: So you implemented `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` method? If yes, what do you return?

Comment: I return the image in the scrollview.

Comment: So I guess that labels can't be zoomed, because they lay not on the view that you resize. You resize imageview. And labels are on scrollview. May be you should add a view that contains ImageView and Labels and return that view from `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`